# How to connect remote server with net.maui on android?I don't want use any php or other api

Tags: .net-6.0

1. My postgresql remote connection string and test code
   using Npgsql;
   namespace JsonTestListView1;

public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
{

```
public TestPage(TestPageViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext=viewModel;

   
}

async void psgBtn_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var connString = "Host=us-west-2.fd8f2a28-c8b2-4cb1-9dfe-b251f5d30e67.aws.ybdb.io;Port=5433;Username=admin;Password=**************;Database=malzemeListesi;sslmode=Prefer;TrustServerCertificate=true;";
        await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Bağlantı BAŞARILI", "Ok");

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Bağlantı başarısız", "Ok");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Doing so is a really bad idea. For one it means giving away the DB password to end users and giving them free database access. You don't want that, really, even for a public database. Use a web server of some kind as an intermediate protective layer, PHP or other.

Answer (score 0):

```
1-mongose ​​and mongoDb also work fine
2-for postgresql in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data to the 
last line of the pg_hba file;
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5 will be added.

3-Create xml folder in Platforms->Android->Resources and create 
network_security_config.xml file.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
<domain includeSubdomains="true">host_ip_1,host_ip_2</domain>
</domain-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
<trust-anchors>
<certificates src="system" />
</trust-anchors>
</base-config>
</network-security-config>
will be arranged as
4-AndroidMaifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" 
 android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
<application android:allowBackup="true" 
android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" 
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" 
android:supportsRtl="true" 
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"> 
</application >
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
will be arranged.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).